# How to know when to use "someone" or "anyone"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, quantifiers, negative-polarity-items, some-any

I am trying to write a grammar rule that will be able to identify when to use *someone* or *anyone*, and I got confused. I couldn't find any clear way to do this.

For instance, "anyone can do it" is totally different from "someone can do it", but since both are pronouns referring to unknown entities, it's extremely difficult to predict the correctness of the grammar.

Any suggestions or am I missing something?

Comment: *Any* is a [negative-polarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) item. At least in Standard English.

Comment: Related/dupe? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/any-or-some-in-various-questions?rq=1

Comment: See new answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88224/14666

Comment: That's the Free-Choice _any_ -- _open_ means Possible in this context, and FC _any_ is a Possible-Polarity Item, requiring some (or any) Possible Modal (_may, possible/y, maybe, X-able/-ible, ..._) in context. Just as NPI _any_ requires a semantically Negative in context. Quantifiers and Negation and Modality are all semantic [Operators](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), and their interactions are [***complicated***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: also related: [anyone vs. everyone](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77058/what-is-the-difference-between-anyone-and-everyone-in-this-context/77077#77077)

Comment: Another related question (with an answer by me):  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/anyone-vs-someone-which-one/86284

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. There ***is*** no clear way to do this. Robin Lakoff's paper entitled ["Some Reasons Why There Can't Be *some ~ any* Rule"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/411442?uid=3739960&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101202045593) is precisely about this situation.

Short summary of a few of the reasons:

1. *Any* is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), but *some* isn't.
2. Many environments (like questions) allow NPIs like *any*, but don't disallow *some*.
3. There are several kinds of *any*, including NPI *any*, and "Free Choice" *any*, as in

   - *Any idiot can solve this problem.*

Comment: Really quite unfortunate, English seems to be really so ambiguous and sorta incomplete, I don't see why no one care about changing it. It just frustrates the idea of artificial intelligence... :(

Comment: Why try to change what English speakers do? You might as well try to change their religions. Change artificial intelligence instead; that, at least, is potentially improvable. For one thing, synchronize intonation, stress, rhythm, gaze direction, and brow movement with the sound. Ignore written English; it's just a frozen obsolete version of AI (0.002 Beta; 0.001 was Latin).

Comment: Funny enough, some people already saw this problem and developed [ROILA...](http://roila.org/)

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Artificial Intelligence is no match for natural languages.

Comment: And I'll prove you and any other willing to stand by your side wrong :)

Answer (score 6):

> Someone can do it.

There is **at least one** person who can do it. The others may or may not be able to do, it is not stated.

> Anyone can do it.

**Every** single member can do it. There is no one who cannot do it.

Comment: This is only true when there is a possibility modal like _can_ in the sentence. Try a sentence frame like ".... did it yesterday" for contrast.

Answer (score 1):

Use "someone" when some elements of a certain group are involved, but not all of the elements. So "someone can do it" means that not everyone from that group can do it, but some can.

Use "anyone" when all elements of a group are involved, but you don't necessarily mean *all* of them. So "anyone can do it" would mean that everybody in that group could do it, even though it doesn't take them *all* to do it.